# Prove that $d_2=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left|{x_j-y_j}\right|$ is a complete metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove that $d_2\left({x,y}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left|{x_j-y_j}\right|$ is a complete metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$. Here is my reasoning for why it is, but I am unsure about its correctness.

The first three properties of a metric are omitted for brevity, where as the triangle inequality property can be shown as follows. Since $\left|{x_j-y_j}\right| \leq \left|{x_j-z_j}\right| + \left|{z_j-y_j}\right|$, summing up this inequality for $j=1,2,...,k$ gives $\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left|{x_j-y_j}\right| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{k}\left|{x_j-z_j}\right|  + \sum_{j=1}^{k}\left|{z_j-y_j}\right|$. Hence, $d_2\left({x,y}\right) \leq d_2\left({x,z}\right) + d_2\left({z,y}\right)$ and is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

To show that $d_2\left({x,y}\right)$ is complete, I must show that a Cauchy sequence $\left({x_n}\right)$ converges to an element of $\mathbb{R}^k$, i.e. that $x_j^n$ for each $j=1,2,...,k$ converges to an element of $\mathbb{R}$. So I must determine whether there exists $N$ such that $n,m>N\implies \left|{x_j^n-x_j^m}\right|<\epsilon$. Since $d\left({x,y}\right)$ is a complete metric on $\mathbb{R}$, and for any $j$ we see that $\left|{x_j^n-x_j^m}\right|=d\left({x_j^n,x_j^m}\right)$ it follows that $x_j^n$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $j=1,2,...,k$ and thus $\left({x_n}\right)$ converges in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: You are not done after that last step. You can find a candidate for the limit of $(x_n)$ this way, but you must then demonstrate that it is indeed the limit. But this isn't hard, it comes straight from the definition of a limit.

Comment: I edited my post a few minutes after you made this last comment, am I still missing it? If I'm still messing this up, maybe there is some reading I could be referred to?

Comment: Good! If you wanted to cover all bases you could show why convergence of the components implies convergence of the sequence, but that proof is pretty obvious. Also, there is another way to prove completeness without using Cauchy sequences: show that $d_2$ is an equivalent metric to the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there! You're a bit confused on the exposition.

It's true that $|x_j-y_j|\leq d(x,y)$, but saying $|x_j-y_j|$ converges makes no sense, since this is not even a sequence; rather, this is the difference in the $j$-th components of $x$ and $y$. Go back to your original sequence $(x_n)$ and apply what you've just said. You want to say that the the *components* of the $x_n$-s are Cauchy sequences. From this, you can actually extract the components of the limit of your sequence $(x_n)$. How?

Comment: $\lim{\left({x_n}\right)} = \left({\lim{x_1^n},\lim{x_2^n},...,\lim{x_k^n}}\right)$. Now if I can show that $\lim{x_j^n}\in\mathbb{R}$ for $j=1,2,...,k$, will that prove that $\left({\mathbb{R},d_2}\right)$ is a complete metric space? Is it true that the limit of a sequence is the vector of the limits of its components?

Comment: Notice: $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is precisely the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. And we know $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with this metric.

Comment: I'm stuck on a couple concepts for this proof. Does the fact that my arbitrary sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy imply that its components are Cauchy? Or is that only for the standard metric? Must I prove that the components are Cauchy, or do I just need to prove that the point to which they converge is is $\mathbb{R}$ and thus $x_n$ converges to some point in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: So from your sequence $(x_n)$ you've got $k$ sequences of real numbers $(x_n^1),\ldots,(x_n^k)$, right? (These numbers are the components of $x_n$.) You can show that each of these sequences of *real numbers* is Cauchy. This isn't difficult: use the fact that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy w.r.t $d_2$. Of course, once you know the components are Cauchy, you get that they converge in $\mathbb{R}$ as well, by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, I edited my original post to reflect my interpretation of what you're saying. I hope I'm getting the point :/